# How to implement a method for an existing interface

Tags: go

I'm writing a command line program that handles network-related stuff using the [`net`](https://pkg.go.dev/net) package. I also use the [`flag`](https://pkg.go.dev/net) package to parse command line arguments.

The user enters an address like so: `./prog 127.0.0.1:8080`. An address is represented by `net.Addr`. Now, `flag` can auto-convert an input string to a user-defined type as long as that type implements the [`Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#Value) interface, which contains the conversion function `Set`. So I thought that I just need to implement the `Value` interface for `net.Addr`:

```
func (addr *net.Addr) Set(s string) error {
    // ...conversion happens here
}
```

But it doesn't compile.

```
./main.go:31:6: invalid receiver type *net.Addr (net.Addr is an interface type)
```

I think Rust folks call that blanket implementation--basically I'm saying that any types that implement `net.Addr` should also implement `Value`. Is it possible in Go? If not, what's the best solution for my situation?

---

Edit: I tried to implement the interface on a concrete type instead:

```
func (addr *net.UDPAddr) Set(s string) error {
    // ...conversion happens here
}
```

It still doesn't compile, now for another reason:

```
./main.go:33:6: cannot define new methods on non-local type net.UDPAddr
```

Comment: You should implement the interfaces on your own struct.

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory: `net.Addr` isn't a type, it's an interface. You can't assign a method to an interface, only to a type that may or may not implement said interface. Also `*net.Addr` is a pointer to an interface type, which doesn't make sense. Lastly, adding methods to a type that isn't defined in your package is not something you ought to be doing

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations *"A receiver base type cannot be a pointer or interface type and **it must be defined in the same package as the method**."* i.e. You cannot declare a method for a type outside of the package in which the type is declared. You can, however, [embed](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) the imported type in a custom type and have the custom type implement the remaining methods necessary to satisfy the interface.

Comment: literally *anything* can be made to implement the `net.Addr` interface. Having a function called `Set` that actually *sets* something on those types just seems like you're trying to do something you really shouldn't be doing. Maybe tell us what you're trying to do, and why you think having a `Set` function on an interface makes sense

Comment: [flag.Func](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#Func) (introduced in Go 1.16) may be useful here.

Answer (score 1):

To make a type implement an interface in go, you just have to define methods with the corresponding signature.

However, it is only possible to define a method to a ***concrete type*** (ie not an interface) defined in the ***same package***.

Thus it is impossible to make a foreign type implement a new interface, or define a method to an existing interface

Comment: This is partially inaccurate. You can define methods on any concrete type, not just structs. The only types you can't define a method for are interfaces.